# PHP 7: Redis extenstion doesn't load (PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library)

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

Recently, I've upgraded PHP to version 7.0.4. After that I tried to re-install Redis client (PHP Redis) by following steps similar to these [instructions](https://anton.logvinenko.name/en/blog/how-to-install-redis-and-redis-php-client.html).

However, when I run PHP I get the following error:

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/redis.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/redis.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/redis.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/redis.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I guess `phpredis` is still does not support `PHP7`. Kindly check https://pecl.php.net/package/redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In beginning of march 2016 stable branch of phpredis does not support php7. But you can use it with [php7-brunch](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/tree/php7). It still has [some bugs](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php7) but actually can be used.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to clone that branch but for some reason it cannot be found:

$ sudo git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/tree/php7 phpredis

Cloning into 'phpredis'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/tree/php7/' not found

Comment: sudo git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git and next sudo git checkout php7

Comment: Thanks! That helped! :)